# Logback with logstash-logback-encoder: RegexValueMasker usage in order to mask values

Tags: logstash-logback-encoder

I want to mask sensitive values in log messages by using standard **RegexValueMasker** instead of writing custom one.

**MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator** was added to my **logback.xml** file, but there is lack in documentation:
https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder#masking

According to **RegexValueMasker** implementation I can pass **regex pattern** into **logback.xml**, is there a chance to get some sample usage of above mentioned ValueMasker.

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
        <defaultMask>****</defaultMask>
        <value>regex-expression</value> // ???
        <valueMasker class="net.logstash.logback.mask.RegexValueMasker"/>
    </jsonGeneratorDecorator>

    <!-- because of https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/387 -->
    <findAndRegisterJacksonModules>false</findAndRegisterJacksonModules>
</encoder>
```